# Autodesk Forge Viewer three.min.js Error not found

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have used the tutorial https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/
and now I have an error:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js 404 Not found
What's happend with this js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected since Viewer v5, the `three.min.js` is no longer required. Your app should version the references, in this case `?v=v5.0` (or any other version).

As it seems your app is using an older version, just add the specific versioning and it should work, e.g. `three.min.js?v=v4.2`